# Getting the username of a domain user from the display name using Python

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I have a list of names from people that made bookings on a system and I'd like to use this names to discover their usernames in Windows 10.

I can read usernames from people in the domain if I, for example, want to share a folder.
But doing it manually is not an option, since I have more than 1000 names, and I have to do it monthly.

After some research I found the Python module win32api, but there I can only get the Display Name from username, not the other way.

Is there some hints for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `NetQueryDisplayInformation` for get  array of `NET_DISPLAY_USER` structures. here `usri1_name` - what you need and `usri1_full_name` - "display name"

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, @rbmm. I don't have a solid knowledge in Python, so here I come with more questions: 
Is NetQueryDisplayInformation  part of a module in Python? If yes, which one?

Comment: [`NetQueryDisplayInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netquerydisplayinformation) exported from *Netapi32.dll* (really from *samcli.dll*). this can be called from python but i dont know how. and i assume that what you called `Display Name` is `usri1_full_name`

Comment: I doubt that display names are unique across a domain.

Comment: @IInspectable they are, because the names are displayed with the department codes

Comment: That may be correct in your case, where you have a protocol outside of the system, that ensures this. In general, this is not the case, though, and I was trying to make the point that going from display name to user name suggests that your overall strategy is backwards. There is no general solution outside of guessing. And guessing can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, but not the way I wanted. Despite that, I learned a lot. Thanks for all the comments.

After installing Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10 I could export usernames display names and departments of all workers and link it with my lists via MS Access.